# What is the difference between a thread entry function and a normal function?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I would like to know the difference between a thread entry function:

```
void* thread_function (void* parameter)
{
   struct parameter * thread_data = (struct parameter *)parameter;
   char buffer[20];
   int temp;
   printf_buffer(buffer);
}
```

and a normal function:

```
void printf_buffer(char *buffer)
{
    printf("buffer is %s",buffer);
    return;
}
```

I know a thread entry is called when a thread is created, and how normal functions are used.

Are there any other differences between thread entry functions and a normal functions in terms of execution , behavior, or creating instances?

Comment: Define "thread function" and "normal function" please.

Comment: question is unclear. What function/library are you thinking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in the language between what you call a "thread function" (although Justin has edited to call it a "thread entry function") and what you call a "normal function".

With pthreads, the so-called "start routine" of a thread is a function that takes a single `void*` parameter and returns `void*`, but there's nothing to stop you calling the same function "normally".

When the start routine of a thread returns, the thread finishes execution, but that's just because the threading implementation calls it, and then finishes the thread. It's not because of anything special to do with the start routine itself.

Answer (score 1):

A thread function is just the entry/exit point of a thread. The execution of that function is no different from what you refer to as a normal function.

Comment: see in ma upper example if i have created 5 thread so each thread function will have different value in buffer & now when printf_buffer of all thread function wil work correctly.? i mean does there will be 5 instances of printf_buffer ..?

Comment: @Mr. 32: there's no such thing as an "instance" of a function. There is only one `printf_buffer` function. There is only one `thread_function` function. Automatic variables are created separately for each invocation of a function, regardless of whether those invocations are in the same thread or different threads.

Comment: @Steve: I think "instance" was being used as a synonym for "invocation" as it's use in 5.2.3...

Comment: @R..: true, although I suspect not entirely deliberately.

Answer (score 1):

`man pthread_create` defines it quite well:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create

one major difference that has not been mentioned yet is that the thread entry should expect to operate on a stack other than the caller's. for this reason, you will often want to pass heap copies of resources as your argument when your thread is detached, then free it in the entry:

```
// the caller must pass a heap copy of struct parameter* arg
void* detached_entry(void* arg) {

  struct parameter* parameter = (struct parameter*)arg;
  ...
  free(parameter);
}
```